# What is view-only password?

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to change my password for Win-Kex. But it ask me for view-only password. What is view-only password? What is the purpose of this password.

```
┌──(sanniddha㉿DESKTOP-TG86V73)-[~]
└─$ kex --passwd
Password:
Verify:
Would you like to enter a view-only password (y/n)?
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found in the article
[How to install Kali Linux with Win-KeX (GUI) in WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://miloserdov.org/?p=4945&PageSpeed=noscript):

> You might think this is the Linux user's password, but you didn't guess – it's not even entering the password, but setting a new VNC password. Therefore, come up with and enter a password twice (at least 6 characters long) and then enter "n", which means that the password gives the right not only to watch what is happening in the system (and nothing will happen there without your participation), but also to move and click the mouse and enter data from the keyboard.

Entering "n" will give the watcher the right to participate actively.
The option "y" will only give the right to watch.

Comment: Which option should I choose "y" or "n"? Which is the secure and best?

Comment: The option "y" will will prevent the watchers from interfering, if that's what you want.

Comment: What is "watchers" here ?

Comment: These are participants in a VNC session. A VNC session may have two or more participants.

Comment: How other can participate in a session ? How is it possible in Win-Kex ?

Comment: [Virtual Network Computing (VNC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) is a graphical desktop-sharing system. You may be the server, showing your desktop, or the client watching someone else's desktop. Each such connection is called a VNC session.